# How to schedule Python script to run hourly, from the script itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

I have a Python (2.7) script I need to run once every hour, every day.
I found two main ways to do this, both won't work for my needs:

- Sleep based solution - I've seen examples that will basically open a thread that loops indefinitely, and sleeps for an hour in between. That won't work because I can't guarantee the process will stay open continuously.
- Manually use Windows' Task Scheduler. The problem with this is that I need to distribute to computers I won't have physical access too, so I won't be able to set up the task.

What I need is an automated way to insure the script runs every hour reliably. Preferably the solution will use Python, but I can run a setup script/program that won't be in python.

Added to that, it would be great if there's a 'correct' set it to run hourly until it succeeds a certain task, but that should be an easy addition once I sort out the hourly scheduling, which is my main need.
**Edit:** The script will probably run only on non-server windows machines.
Thank you!

Comment: Fork it with **os.fork** then sleep-based solution in the forked process.

Comment: are you running your python script in a server? then it should not shutdown without any notification. You can do research on "powershell" which can execute scripts in Windows remotely

Comment: If you have an AWS account, you can run it in lambda as a cronjob.

Comment: @Organis He's pretty clearly on WIndows, given that he's talking about using WIndows' Test Scheduler, so he doesn't have `os.fork`.

Comment: Your problem, as defined, is impossible. You can't do anything from within the script to run every day if you can't guarantee the process stays open continuously for multiple days. It doesn't even make sense. So, one of those has to give: either you have to do this from outside the script, or you have to find a way to guarantee the process runs continuously. Which one do you want?

Comment: Meanwhile: I'm pretty sure there's an API to add new tasks to Windows Task Scheduler. So, you don't need physical access to each computer; you just need to have an "installer" script that adds the task to run your main script. (Or you can even have the main script add itself as a task if it's not already present.) Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006(v=vs.85).aspx). (It looks like you may need PyWin32/PyCOM or one of the .NET bindings, but hey, that's Windows…)

Comment: @abarnert You're totally right, but it's never too late to help a lost soul to escape from the Dark Side. Maybe he'll reconsider and go Linux? Then **os.fork**.

Comment: @Organis Maybe we can `fork` him and run the persistent version as a Linux developer, even though we can't guarantee that the original Windows developer process will live beyond around 4 score years. :)

Comment: @abarnert, an "installer" script is should work just fine. However, I couldn't find any way to create one to solve this problem, also didn't see the API you mention anywhere. I'll try to look in to it though.

Comment: @RickM. I gave a link to the MSDN docs. The link probably tells you have to do it in native C++ and in .NET scripting, and not how to do it in Python. But if so, you can then google for how to call those functions from Python. The answer will probably be PyWIn32/PyCOM, unless you want to, e.g., use IronPython instead of normal CPython, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @abarnert, Missed the link, my bad. I'll try and make it work. Thanks :)

Comment: haven't tried but... maybe [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)?

Comment: @BPL: Since Windows doesn't have a native `cron` facility, presumably that package has its own tool that has to run continuously. If he can't guarantee his own script being allowed to run continuously, how he he guarantee some other tool? (It seems to me that if this really is a requirement, there's no other option besides Windows Scheduled Tasks.)

Comment: @abarnert Oh, ok, i had missed that part, my bad... In my experience, as an alternative to windows scheduled tasks I'd just use cygwin's cron/crontab, which works really well. Few years ago in the office we'd use it to rsync GBs of data every 10 min and we never complained about it.

Comment: @BPL That's what I personally would probably do too, but Cygwin can cause a lot of confusion for Windows-only people. ("Why does this command work in one shell but not the other?", etc.) Do you know if there's a usable `mingw` (or native) port of one of the `cron`-alikes, which can be installed without needing Cygwin? That might have the same benefits with less of risk of confusion.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, agree, the cygwin's setup can be a little pain (cygrunsrv, net start, cygwin shell, ...), although it's definitely worth. I've made a fast experiment and built this little [one](https://github.com/Orc/cron) using msys2, which requires you to have a mail software (used mutt)... and I got both cron.exe and crontab.exe (haven't tested them), OP could give it a shot. Another choice if you don't want to deal with all of this pain would be using a lightweight pythonic solution like [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) which is pip installable... or visualcron maybe?

Comment: @BPL Yeah, `schedule` is a nice idea. And if Visualcron is what it sounds like (a native Windows cron-like that lets you schedule tasks with textfiles instead of COM, but also has an interface Windows people can understand), that too.